Is it feasible to use LLM for natural language detection?
Huge models are trained on data in multiple languages, so I would like to use such model to detect the language of the input. I would extract paragraphs from a webpage, then have the AI analyze the text and spit out something like "the majority of the text is in English, small parts are in German and Swedish".
Is it a feasible application for an LLM? Or will a simple frequency analysis for language detection be more accurate and efficient?

An LLM probably can do this with reasonable accuracy, but it's like swatting flies with a sledgehammer.  You'd get comparable if not better performance from purely statistical methods, while requiring orders of magnitude fewer computing resources.

why the downvote?

I don't personally find downvotes offensive, so feel free to cast any vote :)

@FranckDernoncourt, I'd guess that it's because this is yet another case of "Hi, I found this cool-looking hammer.  How do I use it to install screws?"

The question is not "how do I use it", but rather "is it a good tool for this purpose". And "no" is an acceptable answer if it's backed by something.

Simple frequency analysis for language detection is orders of magnitude more efficient from a computational standpoint, and I'm guessing at least as good as LLMs. Just need to look a n-gram char stats (typically yields >99% accuracy in most language detection scenarios), with sliding windows if suspecting code-mixing (code-mixing significantly degrades language detection accuracy).
